# Python, cant overide a method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code it will print "1" from the class parent_model_admin even I specified  `super(admin_base, self).test()` method, How do i print "2" in admin_base but through in admin class ?

```
class theme():
    pass

class parent_model_admin():

    def test(self):
        print("1")
        pass
    pass


class admin_base(theme,parent_model_admin):
    def test(self):
        print("2")
        pass
    pass


class user(parent_model_admin):
    def test(self):
        print("3")
        pass
    pass


class admin(user, admin_base):
    def test(self):
        super(admin_base, self).test()
        pass
    pass

hai = admin()
hai.test()
```

Comment: if i'm understanding you correct, why not just `print("3")` in `admin` class?

Comment: The issue here is called Method Resolution Order (MRO).  See the answer to the duplicate question for details of how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `admin` class to:

```
class admin(user, admin_base):
    def test(self):
        super(user, self).test()
        pass
    pass
```

Use `super(user, self).test()` instead.

Full code:

```
class theme():
    pass

class parent_model_admin():

    def test(self):
        print("1")
        pass
    pass


class admin_base(theme,parent_model_admin):
    def test(self):
        print("2")
        pass
    pass


class user(parent_model_admin):
    def test(self):
        print("3")
        pass
    pass


class admin(user, admin_base):
    def test(self):
        super(user, self).test()
        pass
    pass

hai = admin()
hai.test()
```

Output:

```
2
```